# Package or namespace load failed for 'tcltk'

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to include the "tcltk" library under a R script in Azure Machine Learning Studio (R version 3.1.0). But I am always getting this error:

> package or namespace load failed for 'tcltk'

Any ideas please.

Thanks in advance.

Error message:

```
Error 0063: The following error occurred during evaluation of R script:
---------- Start of error message from R ----------
package or namespace load failed for 'tcltk'

package or namespace load failed for 'tcltk'
----------- End of error message from R -----------
Start time: UTC 06/24/2019 11:27:02
End time: UTC 06/24/2019 11:27:08
```

Answer (score 0):

> Package ‘tcltk’ was removed from the CRAN repository.
>
> Formerly available versions can be obtained from the archive.

Changing the R version to Microsoft R Open 3.4.4 solved the issue.

```
library(tcltk)
```

> Microsoft R Open is the enhanced distribution of R from Microsoft
>   Corporation. It is a complete open source platform for statistical
>   analysis and data science.

However, if it is crucial for you to use CRAN 3.1.0 let me know, I will try to install the package manually and publish it to the Azure ML Gallery